# What is the equivalent of facet_wrap in Lattice

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

Say we have some data like this:

```
dta <- data.frame(
   group = rep(letters[1:8], each=1000), 
   x = runif(8000), y=runif(8000)
)
```

I would like to produce a Lattice plot containing y ~ x for each group. But, with groups a-d on the first row, and e-h on the second row. i.e., I would like to do the equivalent of

```
 qplot(x=x, y=y, data=dta) + facet_wrap(~ group, nrow=2)
```

But in Lattice. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: hmm, it looks in this like it's as simple as adding layout = c(2,4) (https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-4/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y ~ x | group, dta, layout=c(4,2), as.table = TRUE)
```

As suggested by @BenBarnes, `as.table = TRUE` keeps the order of the facets.

[image]

Comment: Nevertheless, the result is nicer and faster in ggplot2

Comment: Thanks - had basically answered the question through asking it (often the way).
I agree that usually ggplot2 is better in terms of usability and default aesthetics. I definitely wouldn't use it for the toy example above. However it was actually for a composite contour plot - combining shade from one variable with contour lines based on another - and Lattice labels contours, whereas ggplot2 does not. For the end result, see :
https://github.com/JonMinton/Gender_Mortality_Differences/raw/master/images/tiled_difference.tiff 
Thanks, Jon

Comment: If you include `as.table = TRUE` to the `xyplot` call, you can get a-d in row 1 and e-h in row 2.